# Rcursive function with and without return in the recursive step

Tags: python, recursion, return

Can someone explain me the difference between these two codes?

```
def pal(s):
    if s == "":
        return True
    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False
    return pal(s[1:-1])

a = "anna"

print(pal(a))
```

and

```
def pal(s):
    if s == "":
        return True
    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False
    pal(s[1:-1])

a = "anna"

print(pal(a))
```

Why the firts one return the right value, that is `True`, and the second return me `None`?

Comment: If you have more than 1 iteration, you have a recursive process. In the 2nd code, you just ask to compute the same function , but you don't ask for a return in the end. The thing returned will be the thing inside your "return" block of the 1st iteration, so if you don't call `return` before the `pal(s[1:-1])` the function will just compute the thing but not return anything

Comment: Ok but when I arrive at the last iteration(recursion) with the empty string, shouldn't  it returns "True"?

Comment: It changes the code in **the same way** that it would change the code if you did **the same thing** with **any other** function call. Returning the value vs. just getting that value and ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is returning the value of recursive solution with the line:

> return pal(s[1:-1])

Whereas the second one is just returning a void/None, and not the solution of recursive method.